# What will happen if I send an analog signal through a digital regenerator?

Tags: signal, digital-logic

What will happen if I send an analog signal through a digital regenerator?

Comment: This should be on audio.stackexchange or electronics.stackexchange.

Comment: What do you mean by "digital regenerator"? Schmitt-trigger, latch, or comparator?

Comment: @tyblu - This is a question migrated from Superuser (Didn't know we could do that yet!).  Porramate Lim doesn't have an account here, so he probably can't answer your question.

Comment: @reemrevnivek, I'm hoping someone else knows. Anyway, I guessed CMOS buffer.

Answer (score 6):

A [digital regenerator](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/5197082.html) will ruin an [analog signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_signal).

Some analog signals will ruin some digital regenerators.

Most digital signals should have two distinct signal levels, labelled "0" and "1".
A digital regenerator will attempt to force any input signal into a sequence of these two levels.

An analogue signal has an infinite number of values between certain fixed limits. It is vital to the fidelity of the signal that this range of possible values not be reduced (quantised) below some quality threshold. For an analog signal that threshold is much much greater than two.

[image: ANalogue and DIgital Signals]
<sub>(source: [antonine-education.co.uk](http://www.antonine-education.co.uk/Electronics_AS/Electronics_Mod2/topic_2_4/graph_1.gif))</sub>

In the above diagram, a digital regenerator might convert the signal on the right to that on the left. If you fed this result to an analogue amplifier and into a loudspeaker the result would not be pleasant and the equipment might not survive.

More complex digital signals encode multiple bits of data per bit of signal - this may involve more than two signal states - for example more than two voltage levels. However it is very unlikely that a digital signal regenerator attempting to find such a digital signal in an unrelated analogue signal will happen to do anything useful.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what a *digital regenerator* is, as digital signals are reconstructed whenever they pass through a digital element (simplest would be an inverter), but I'll go with this: a buffer, made from two inverters.
[image]

```
Inverter
Vin 1 0 SIN(2.5 2.5 10k 1ns 0)
Vcc 2 0 5
M1  3 1 2 2 MP
M2  3 1 0 0 MN
M3  4 3 2 2 MP
M4  4 3 0 0 MN
RL  4 0 1Meg
.model MP PMOS level=2
.model MN NMOS level=2
.control
delete all
tran 30ns 6ms 0 100ns
plot V(1) V(4)
.endc
.END
```

[image: sinusoid input, asynchronous]
<sub>(source: [tyblu.ca](http://www.tyblu.ca/misc/inverter2.png))</sub>

If the inverter is clocked, however, it will look a bit different. Here's the same example with a 32.768 kHz clock:

```
Inverter
Vin 1 0 0 SIN(2.5 2.5 10k 10ns 0)
Vcc 2 0 5
Vclk    9 0 0 PULSE(0 5 0 10ns 10ns 0.5us 1us)
M1  3 9 2 2     MP
M2  4 1 3 2     MP
M3  4 1 5 0     MN
M4  5 10 0 0    MN
M5  6 10 2 2    MP
M6  7 4 6 2     MP
M7  7 4 8 0     MN
M8  8 9 0 0     MN
M9  10 9 2 2    MP
M10 10 9 0 0    MN
RL  7 0 10k
.model MP PMOS level=2
.model MN NMOS level=2
.control
delete all
tran 4ns 400us
plot V(1) V(4)
.endc
.END
```

[image: 32kHz clocked buffer]
<sub>(source: [tyblu.ca](http://www.tyblu.ca/misc/inverter1.png))</sub>

... and with a 1 MHz clock:

[image: 1MHz clocked buffer]
<sub>(source: [tyblu.ca](http://www.tyblu.ca/misc/inverter3.png))</sub>

There are many variation this can and is likely to take, such as Schmitt trigger input conditioning, different clock schemes, and output voltage clamping.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine it'll get sampled much like music does on a computer. So it'll take the value of the signal at a given rate (the sample rate), and record it as a discreet level, that value of which depends on how many levels it uses to distinguish the wave.

Just a guess.

With a good enough digital regenerator, the wave should look similar.